# ArcScene Extruding between constant TIN's to calculate bed volume within oil window?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, tin, extrude

I don't seem to be able to extrude between two TINs created from constant rasters.

Will the extrusion tool not work between TINs which are copied and pasted and altered in position by me after their creation?